# cursor url image found but not displayed

Tags: css, image, cursor

As you can see on the following page: http://www.reithalle.sg/

I want to use a *.gif or a *.png image as a cursor on the lay-over div.
Firebug tells me that the css is being interpreted correctly and the image is being found.

Never the less, the cursor image is not displayed (in none of the browsers I've tested).

```
cursor: url('http://www.reithalle.sg/reithalle/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/Ja.gif'), pointer;
```

Does anyone have a clue why it isn't working?

Comment: The problem was that the image was too big. Most browsers only allow Pictures smaller than 128px width / height

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the cursor put it in your website folder and implent it like:

```
.cursor {
cursor: url(cursor/anynameyougiveit.gif) auto;
}
```

if you are using something like wordpress the url is like this:

```
.cursor {
cursor: url('http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theThemeYouUse/images/Ja.gif') auto;
}
```

Hope this works for you too